# Symfony3 - Assets not working properly in Production

Tags: php, apache, symfony, assets

My SF3 application is working just fine in dev built-in PHP server. However some assets give me an error when getting to a production Apache server : the images are showing a 404 error, and a Bundle triggers a 505 code. Here's 2 screens of the Chrome console where you can see the errors :

- Dev:
  [image: Dev]
- Prod:
  [image: Prod]

I've been trying many things (checking the Apache conf files, emptying the cache, the install:assets command even thoug I'm just using the classic Twig syntax and no Assetic, etc) and browsed tons of topics over the internet in vain.

Here's my config.yml file just in case :

```yaml
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: "@ABundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
    - { resource: "@AnotherBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
        save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
        # save_path: /var/lib/php/sessions
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~
    php_errors:
        log: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    paths:
      "%kernel.root_dir%/../app/Resources/views/modules": modules

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/data/data.sqlite"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

I'm really stuck on this one, so thank you in advance guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried: `php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug` ?

also, your assets should be in `src/YourBundle/Resources/public` directory. Then when you install them with `php bin/console assets:install --symlink` they should be copied or symlinked to `web/bundles/your` directory

Comment: Accordingly to the console,
 this command doesn't exist under SF3 :
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]  
  Command "assetic" is not defined.                               
  Did you mean this?                                              
      assets:install

Comment: That is probably because you don't have Assetic installed. http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/asset_management.html

Comment: I installed Assetic and run the command, but this didn't solve the problem. Thank you for your answer though !

I usually put the assets inside the /web folder, as the documentation recommends ("Store your assets in the web/ directory." : http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html ). Is this a mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that my assets were in the web folder instead of the Resources. Then the assetic:dump command worked perfectly.
Thanks a lot

Comment: It was a pleasure to me!